# Django: can't import custom variable from settings

Tags: django

I've defined a custom variable `mongo_db` in settings.py:

```
# connect to test database for tests and real database otherwise
if is_test():
    mongo_db = mongoengine.connect(db='test-workflows', host='workflows-mongo')
else:
    mongo_db = mongoengine.connect(db='workflows', host='workflows-mongo')
```

Now, I'm trying to import it from `tests.py` (or from `python manage.py shell`), both unsuccessfully:

```
from django.conf import settings
settings.mongo_db
AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'mongo_db'
```

What's wrong?

**UPDATE:**
IIRC, Django constructs `django.conf.settings` by overriding its default settings object `django.conf.global_settings` with values, defined in your `settings.py`.

So, what might be wrong in `from django.conf import settings; settings.mongo_db` is that Django might not update `django.conf.settings` with `mongo_db`, as it isn't among default options.

Also, [Django documentation says](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/#using-settings-in-python-code) that `django.conf.settings` is an **object**, not a **module**, so you can not say `from django.conf.settings import VARIABLE`. Luckily, I'm not doing that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to import from django's settings and not your own settings.py

```
from django.conf import settings
```

should be

```
from your_app import settings
```

Comment: Right, thank you. Used `from workflows import settings` and it worked. Will accept the answer in 9 minutes

Comment: Also, you were doing a real connection in settings from what I can see, maybe that's not suitable for settings. Settings should store static info instead of initiating real database connections. You could store a dictionary like `{db: 'test-workflows', 'host': 'workflows-mongo'}` then do the `connect()` in your `test.py`.

Comment: @ShangWang That's generally a nice idea, but I need a global pool of connections to mongodb stored somewhere. Initializing it in `views.py`, `test.py` (and, potentially, in `manage.py shell`) wouldn't be suitable. I can't think of a better place for such a global object.

Comment: @ShangWang - I agree although the question was about how to use a settings variable

Answer (score 6):

Import is failing because you are not following django [guidelines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#available-settings).

**For creating your own settings.**

> 1. Setting names must be all uppercase.
> 2. Don’t reinvent an already-existing setting.
>
> Note that your code should not import from either global_settings or your own settings file.
>
> django.conf.settings abstracts the concepts of default settings and site-specific settings; it presents a single interface.

Change your code in settings.py like this. (replace `mongo_db` with `MONGO_DB`)

```
if is_test():
    MONGO_DB = mongoengine.connect(db='test-workflows', host='workflows-mongo')
else:
    MONGO_DB = mongoengine.connect(db='workflows', host='workflows-mongo')
```

Now you can import from django shell and from all other places.